# Absolute references in table formulas

Tags: excel-formula

I apologize for the remedial question...  I have not had to rely on my excel formulas in quite a while now.  I am having trouble with absolute references in a table.  I have conditional formatting that I would like to apply every time I add a new row to the table, but conditional formatting is getting in the way.  Here is a screen shot of what I am seeing.

[image]

Each time a new row is added to the table the absolute reference is holding the previous cell.  I know there is a way to get around this I just cant seem to find it.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place the cursor in your desired column of the table
2. Press Ctrl+Spacebar which selects the entire column of the table.
3. Apply CF which will get applied for new entries also.

Tested and it's working fine for me for new entries.